# mysql workbench forward engineer not an option

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, forward-engineer

I'm attempting to forward engineer from mySQL workbench. I know to do so I go to database --> forward engineer, but it is not currently an option. It does not appear when I search in help/ spotlight either. Any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not currently an option"? Is the menu entry disabled or don't you find it?

Answer (score 3):

First of all check that you have selected the MySQL model or EER diagram tab first.
The database menu there includes the forward engineer option.

Database menu option in connection tabs, do not have the Forward Engineer option.

Answer (score 1):

First select the EER Diagram tab and type shift ctrl z. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When I had faced this issue, I couldn't find the answer to resolve it. For time being I use **CTRL + G** which is the shortcut to the Forward Engineer option and it works for me.